# Typescript: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: typescript

Trying to figure out a simple way to drop decimals of a number in TypeScript.  Based on what I could find, the ParseInt method should work, but getting the error

```
Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'
```

Code:

```
function testFunction (frame_count: number, frame_count_correct: number): number {
let score: number = 0 
if (frame_count > 1) {
    score = frame_count_correct/frame_count
} else {
    score = 0
}

return parseInt(score);
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`score` is `number`. `parseInt` expects `string` argument because its purpose is to parse integers from strings, as function name suggests.

If the intention is to return integer part, `parseInt` isn't needed. Instead, it should be:

```
score = Math.floor(frame_count_correct/frame_count)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use `parseInt` function which is defined to string variables with double typed variable.
Are you sure?
You can use `Math.floor(score)` instead.